# Plugin calendario wordpress

Tags: wordpress

gente estou precisando urgente de um plugin de calendario free, que seja parecido com esse aqui
http://revistagloborural.globo.com/eventos.html
Alguem tem alguma sugestão ?

vlwww

Comment: O objetivo desta comunidade não é este, então sua pergunta provavelmente será fechada em breve. Se você tentar implementar um *plugin* semelhante ou obter algum erro durante sua utilização, sua pergunta será bem-vinda aqui.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse calendário está parecendo do plugin **flatpickr**. https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/

Recomendo fortemente, é o melhor plugin que já utilizei!

```js
flatpickr("#inline", {
 inline: true,
 weekNumbers: true
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://chmln.github.io/flatpickr/bower_components/flatpickr/dist/themes/material_green.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/flatpickr"></script>

<input class="flatpickr" type="text" placeholder="Select Date.." id="inline">
```